# Why the probability of a sequence is simply the multiplication?

Tags: probability, random-walk

In studying the random walk in one dimension I had a doubt on basic probability. The point is the following: we consider a random walk with $N$ steps consiting of $n_1$ steps to the right and $n_2$ steps to the left. The probability that one step will be to the right is $p$ and the probability one step will be to the left is $q = 1-p$. Also, it is considered each step is independent of the last one.

The book states, however, that the probability of getting any *one* sequence with $n_1$ steps to the right is simply $p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$, that is, multiplying $p$ by itself $n_1$ times.

Why is that? I know from probability that if $A$ and $B$ are independent events then $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ and the result would follow.

But I can't see how this relates to the present case. Indeed, $A,B$ as above are events of the same sample space $S$, but on the random walk problem it seems we have *two* sample spaces:

- The sample space $S_1$ of the experiment of watching one step. Then $S_1 = \{-1,1\}$ being $-1$ to the left and $1$ to the right, and we have $P(\{-1\}) = q$ and $P(\{1\}) = p$.
- The sample space $S_2$ of the experiment of watching $N$ steps. Then $S_2 = \{(i_1,\dots, i_N) : i_k = -1,1\}$ that is all sequences of steps or to the right or to the left.

How from this could we deduce that the probabilty of any sequence with $n_1$ steps to the right, that is any sequence $(i_1,\dots, i_N)$ with $n_1$ $1$'s appearing is $p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$?

Comment: A sequence of length $N$ that has $n_1$ steps to the right has $N-n_1$ to the left. Any particular such sequence has probability $p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$.

Comment: Yes @AndreNicolas, but how can I prove this?

Comment: Do you mean how do we prove that if $A$ and $B$ are independent then $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$? From the formal point of view, this is the definition of independence. In a concrete situation, we have to decide whether the assumption of independence is reasonable. Note that the formula I gave is somewhat different from the one in the OP.

Comment: I mean how to use this fact to prove the formula for the probability of getting $n_1$ steps to the right. I'm not being able to do it because as I explain on the question it seems to exist more than one sample space on the problem. And also, your formula is right, consulting the book I wrote the wrong formula, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Let $A_i$ be the event we go to the right at step $i$, and $B_i$ be the event we go to the left. We want $\Pr(C_1\cap C_2\cap \cdots \cap C_N)$, where $n_1$ of the $C_i$ are $A_i$ and $N-n_1$ of the $C_i$ are $B_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to define the random walk is to consider independent identically distributed random variables $\xi_n$, with $P(\xi_n=+1)=p$ and $P(\xi_n=-1)=1-p$, and then consider the sum $X_n=\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n$ which gives you the position of the random walk started at $0$ at time $n$.

You can think of the sample space as being sequences of $N$ coin-flips of an unfair coin. If it's heads ($\xi_n=+1$) you move right, if it is tails ($\xi_n=-1$) you move left.

The probability that you have a particular sequence of (at least) $n_1$ steps to the right, say the first steps from time $1$ to $n_1$ are to the right,  is 
$P(\xi_1=1,\xi_2=1,\dots,\xi_{n_1}=1)= P(\xi_1=1)P(\xi_2=1)\cdots P(\xi_{n_1}=1)=p^{n_1}$

Similarly, the probability of any particular sequence consisting of at least $n_1$ steps to the right is $p^{n_1}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering @DimitriosNt, it makes more sense this way really, but just one problem. I wrote the formula wrong, the book really states that it should be $p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$. How this follows from that idea you presented?

Comment: As I wrote, my formula gives you the probability that you have AT LEAST $n_1$ steps to the right. If you want to have precisely $n_1$ steps to the right this means that the rest $N-n_1$ steps are to the left, i.e. $\xi_i=-1$ for $N-n_1$ $i$'s. Therefore using the same idea and independence you can derive the reslt $p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$